# OpenGL transparent objects over background image

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, transparency

Due to the bad performance (high CPU usage) in my [Qt3DOffscreenRenderer](https://github.com/Sonnentierchen/Qt3D-OffscreenRenderer), which uses the Qt3D framework, I implemented a new [offscreen renderer](https://github.com/Sonnentierchen/QtOpenGLOffscreenRenderer) using only/mostly OpenGL.

Unfortunately, I can't get the object drawn on top of the background image to be transparent. I enabled blending and set `glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);`.

The result is the following:

[image]

What you can't see is that the Qt logo's pixels' alpha is 0.5.

For reference, this is the image without transparency:

[image]

I simply want the Qt logo to be a bit transparent, like so:

[image]

I managed to create this image using [this example](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-scenegraph-textureinthread-example.html) and modifing it to use the blend function mentioned above and an alpha value of 0.5 in the shader.

How can I achieve this for the offscreen renderer? I experimented with a lot of parameters but had no luck.

Comment: do you have Alpha buffer in your context? [check the pixelformat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50248477/2521214)  for `cAlphaBits`

Comment: No luck with either suggestion. Inspecting the format of the renderer of the last image even shows that it doesn't have an alpha buffer enabled. I even set the format of the renderer on my offscreen renderer but this still produces the same result.

Comment: see [complete GL+VAO/VBO+GLSL+shaders example in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31913542/2521214) and look for `int  gl_init(HWND Handle);` function how to set pixelformat. However the GL implementation of yours can refuse it and chose closest format to what you set up ... I usually got an ordered  que of formats (decreasing quality) and chose the first that is accepted like this: [What is the proper OpenGL initialisation on Intel HD 3000?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19099162/2521214) just add /set the stuff in `pfd` you need ...

Comment: Hi Spektre, thanks for your reply but I'm on Linux and solved my problem alread ;) See my answer below.

Comment: I did see it. just take in mind that by discarding the alpha channel in your answer you can not use `GL_DST_ALPHA nor GL_ONE_MINUS_DST_ALPHA`

Comment: Ok, well I haven't tried to not set it and inspect the result, but right now it works how I wanted it to work :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that I set the internal texture format of the `QFramebufferObjectFormat` to `GL_RGBA32F` but it needs to be `GL_RGB32F` (i.e. without the alpha channel).